# how to convert string in integer numbers

Tags: c++

I am receiving `string such as "2011-08-12,02:06:30"` from the server which specifies data and time.

But how to convert it into int and store like

`int year = 2011, month =08, day = 14, h = 02, min = 06, sec=30`.

Comment: Sounds like you want to parse a string into a date/time object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `stringstream` class in C++.

```
#include <iostream>
// for use of class stringstream
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string str = "2011-08-12,02:06:30";
   stringstream ss(str);
   int year, month, day, h, min, sec;

   ss >> year;
   ss.ignore(str.length(), '-');
   ss >> month;
   ss.ignore(str.length(), '-');
   ss >> day;
   ss.ignore(str.length(), ',');
   ss >> h;
   ss.ignore(str.length(), ':');
   ss >> min;
   ss.ignore(str.length(), ':');
   ss >> sec;

   // prints 2011 8 12 2 6 30
   cout << year << " " << month << " " << day << " " << h << " " << min << " " << sec << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The [sscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/) function will help you out much here.

```
int year, month, day, h, min, sec;
char * data = "2011-08-12,02:06:30";
sscanf(data, "%d-%d-%d,%d:%d:%d", &year, &month, &day, &h, &min, &sec);
```

Comment: Straightforward and reliable :)

Comment: Ahhh. Not reliable as they don't type check their parameters. In your code it is easy to see but in larger programs if the seonds is defined a long way from the scanf() then a bug fix may result in changing the type of seconds from int to long. Yet the above code would still compile without error.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'defined a long way from the scanf', or 'bug fix'. But no, sccanf does not type check, that's a task for the programmer to validate his input string if required.

Answer (score 3):

You could either write your own string parser to parse the string into the necessary components (something like a Finite State Machine design would be good here), or...

Don't re-invent the wheel, and use something like the [Boost Date & Time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/date_time.html) library.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `strptime()` function on any POSIX-compliant platform, and save the data into a `struct tm` structure.  Once in the format of a `struct tm`, you will also have some additional liberties to take advantage of other POSIX functions the time format as defined by `struct tm`.

For instance, in order to parse the string being sent back from your server, you could do the following:

```
char* buffer = "2011-08-12,02:06:30";
struct tm time_format;
strptime(buffer, "%Y-%d-%m,%H:%M:%S", &time_format);
```